# Vue sync data back to parent

Tags: vue.js

I have got the following component structure:

```
- Root
-- Toolbar
--- Search
```

Within `Root` I have got a data property called `search`, I pass this into `Toolbar`, then `Toolbar` passes it to `Search`. Then within search I have got an input I can type in, this value should then get back to `Root`, `Toolbar` doesn't care about it.

```html
// Root.vue
<toolbar :search.sync="search" />

// Toolbar.vue
<search :search.sync="search" />

// Search.vue
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." v-model="searchValue" @change="$emit('update:search', $event.target.value)">
```

```js
// Search.vue
export default {
    props: {
        search: {
            required: false,
            type: String
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            searchValue: this.search
        }
    },
```

What is the best and cleanest way to do this?

## Edit:

This way works, however I feel like i'm duplicating code by putting the `v-on` even on the middleman

```html
// Root.vue
<toolbar :search.sync="search" />

// Toolbar.vue
<search :search="search" @update:search="$emit('update:search', $event)" />

// Search.vue
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." v-model="searchValue" @change="$emit('update:search', $event.target.value)">
```

Comment: The fact that Toolbar passes on the search even if it doesn't care looks clean to me. Components are as decoupled as they can be with your suggestion. If it's not decoupled enough, did you try using provide/inject instead?

Comment: The above doesn't work though, I get an error stating i'm trying to modify the prop

Comment: (regarding the edit) Well this is how Vue works. Events in Vue do not "bubble up" in the component hierarchy. If you need to share data between multiple components on multiple levels, consider using central store such as Vuex or Pinia. For most simple cases, creating your own global store is also ok. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Answer (score -2):

```
data() {
  return { search: '' }
}

<search :search="search" @search="search = $event" />
```

Search Component

```
<input v-model="search" @change="changeSearch" />

changeSearch(event) { this.$emit('search', event.target.value) }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.